# why is my device not shown when I want to deploy the application?

Tags: android, device

I want to deploy my android application on samsung, my device is not shown in Android device chooser even Samsung kies is installed.I tries all my possibilities but it doesn't work 4 me. Can anybody help me  Your help would be appreciated !!

Comment: Did you enable USB debugging? If yes, are you working on Windows/Mac/Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Check If you have enable USB Debugging and Allow Mock Locations ON in your Device

Answer (score 1):

Make sure In settings -> developers options-> enable USB Debugging
And in terminal, go to platform-tools where you installed android, then give command 
1. adb kill-server then 
2. adb start-server then 
3. adb devices: it should display your device.